# jQuery Mobile: header does not show correctly in calling page

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Here is my `HTML` code

```
<div data-role="page" id="main-body">
    <div data-role="header">
        <!--<a href="#"><img src="img/back.png" width="30" height="30" class="ui-btn-left" /></a>-->
        <img src="img/share.png" width="30" height="30" class="ui-btn-right" />
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
    
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#asked-question-body">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    </ul>          
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="asked-question-body">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#main-body"><img src="img/back.png" width="30" height="30" class="ui-btn-left" /></a>
    </div>
        
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan blandit fermentum. Pellentesque cursus mauris purus, auctor commodo mi ullamcorper nec. Donec semper mattis eros, nec condimentum ante sollicitudin quis. Etiam orci sem, porttitor ut tellus nec, blandit posuere urna. Proin a arcu non lacus pretium faucibus. Aliquam sed est porttitor, ullamcorper urna nec, vehicula lorem. Cras porttitor est lorem, non venenatis diam convallis congue.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it shows `id="main-body"` header perfectly but `id="asked-question-body"` doesn't show its header correctly. I want to show its header perfectly as `main-body` page.

`main-body` screenshot is
[image]

and `asked-question-body`
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in **asked-question-body** page

```
<div data-role="header">
     <h1></h1>
     <a href="#main-body" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-btnback" data-icon="btnback"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 <style>
    .ui-icon-btnback:after {
      background: url(back.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;         
    }
</style>
```